# VBA excel code to create hyperlink to the folderpath mentioned in the cells of column C

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet in which folder path are mentioned in the cells of Column C, I need to create hyperlinks to each cell in Column C so that if I click on it then it will dirent me to that folder for which the path is mentioned in the cell

```
Sub folderpathyperlink ()
    Dim sfolder As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    bottomA = sh.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sfolder = Cells(2, bottomA).Value

    For Each cell In sfolder
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Selection, Address:=sfolder
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: this code is not giving any error, however not creating hyperlinks as well

Comment: I think you define things wrong here. For each cell in sfolder, whilst sfolder is a string and not a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
Sub folderpathyperlink()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range    
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
lr = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lr)
For Each Cell In Rng
    sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:= _
    Cell.Value, TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value
Next Cell
End Sub
```

To check if a cell in column C contains a valid folder path and if that folder exists, insert the hyperlink otherwise skip the code, try the below code...

```
Sub folderpathyperlink()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
lr = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lr)
For Each Cell In Rng
    If Not Dir(Cell.Value, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:= _
        Cell.Value, TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:=Cell.Value, TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value

Comment: The cell value contains folder path, I just want to create a hyperlink so that when I click it directs me to that folder

Comment: I have modified the code and its creating a hyperlink now but when I am clicking on the hyperlink, it says reference not valid, its not redirecting me to that folder. The folder path is correct.

Comment: Sub folderpathyperlink()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
lr = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lr)
For Each Cell In Rng
    sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=Cell.Value & "!A1"
    
Next Cell
End Sub

Comment: sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=Cell.Value

Comment: Its creating the hyperlink but when I am clicking on it then it says reference not valid

Comment: I have edited the answer. See if that resolves the issue. If the values in column C are valid folder path, the code will insert the hyperlinks then.